# Is storing all the countries and cities in the world in the Lucene index a good or bad idea?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have read that I can eliminate a roundtrip to the database when searching for an entity by storing the fields I need inside the index itself. However I've also read that this increases the index and the rule of thumb is that the smaller the index the faster the search. I want to store a country, a city and a float array. It concerns all the cities and countries in the world. So what is faster? Store everything inside the index or retrieve them from the DB?

```
    @Entity
@Indexed
public class Location implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @DocumentId(name = "_documentId")
    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String country;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)    
    private String city;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)    
    private String province;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.NO) 
    private final float[] temperatures = new float[12];

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public float[] getTemperatures() {
        return temperatures;
    }
}
```

Also, could anyone tell me where the Hibernate search projections or Lucene index are stored exactly? They don't seem to be stored as JSON files as is the case with Elastic Search. Is everything stored in RAM memory?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a good or bad idea depends on many factors. Generally I'd expect it to be a good idea, but this is assuming that your database roundtrip is actually slow, and skipping this helps taking some load from the database to keep that processing power available for other queries.

You might be able to obtain the same goal by enabling 2nd level caching of Hibernate though, so you actually have to compare the treadeoffs with three approaches:

- loading them from the Lucene index
- loading them from the Hibernate ORM 2nd level cache (in-heap caching)
- loading from the RDBMS using a JDBC connection

Typically you might want to limit the size of the JVM heap to keep the application responsive and easier to tune GC; this implies the size of the 2nd level cache is limited and possibly needs to be used by other data points which benefit more from the smart eviction algorhytms a proper cache can deliver.

Storing in the Lucene index is an all/nothing approach so you're making a design decision which doesn't automatically balance between memory usage and cache hit usefulness... still the Lucene index is typically stored in memory-mapped filesystem so you're actually benefitting from native memory to cache this, so yes you'll be benefitting from RAM as long as there's some free RAM available for it to use for this purpose.

In short: I think it's worth trying, benefits are *typically* strong. But verify it by measuring!

Comment: Dear Sanne, I've just finished testing and comparing Hibernate search Search method to a regular Spring data jpa using a custom method that searches by Like command. I have found out that when the field is only one word long Hibernate search performs slower then Spring data jpa! Only when I search for a word in a text of 500 words long and storing the field values in the index is ENABLED then HS is only about 120 milliseconds faster then Spring data. if I disable it for the fields it performs slower again. Is this normal or did I miss setting something in the hibernate config file?

Comment: Hi Maurice, no that's not normal but there is no particular setting affecting this. My guess is that the RDBMS you're using for the comparison is not the real one? (if it's an in-memory database as people use for testing it's not representative) Also, the Lucene index needs to have some free native memory to be able to use resources efficiently.